# Java:How to populate jtable with one only column?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have to display authors on a table and I made only 1 column for it. I have used a jtable before but with 2d arrays and multiple columns. I'm having problems with this one.The 'authors name' are stored in mysql.

```
tblAuthor.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
authorData,new String[]{"Name"}){
@Override
public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
    //all cells false
    return false;
}
@Override
public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
    return String.class;
}
})
}
```

this one is how i retrieve the authors

```
private Object[][] getAuthors(int id) throws SQLException{
        sql="SELECT authorName FROM tbl_textbook as b,tbl_txauthor as a where a.bookID=b.bookID AND a.bookID="+id;
    rs=stm.executeQuery(sql);
    rs.next();
    Object authors[][] = new String[countAuthors(id)][1];
    if(rs.getRow()!=0)
         authors=new String[rs.getInt(1)][1];
    i=0;
    while(rs.next()){

        authors[i][1]=rs.getString(1);
        i++;
    }

    return authors;
}
```

I'm a noob so please help.thank you

Answer (score 1):

try

```
   authors[i][0]=rs.getString(1);
```

java array are 0 based unlike resultset that are 1 based